# THREE.js (r70) Why must an OrbitControls object be created?

Tags: three.js

A very simple THREE.js script.
It runs fine in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4smx8rqy/1/).

But if the following line of code:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

is commented out and the JSFiddle is re-run then no graphics are displayed.  I ran equivalent code from a localhost html file with Chrome debugger but it showed no warnings or exceptions.  Same behavior in Firefox.  All runs done on a Windows 7 laptop.

So why does THREE.js seem to require an OrbitControls object in this example?

(I don't specifically need OrbitControl functionality in the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not from the `controls` but the camera. The `.lookAt()` take a vector so you need to call it as `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));`. Otherwise you invalidate the camera instance. If you comment out the `controls` and the `camera.lookAt()` in your fiddle it works.

Comment: Aha, yes, I see. Many thanks gaitat.  I have been working mostly with (r60) where .lookAt() did not require OrbitControls.js.  I wonder why it was moved?

Comment: `.lookAt()` does not require OrbitControls.js

Comment: I just showed you the error in your code way before your call to the controls. So I have shown that the code works with and without the controls. You are asking now; I have an error on line 10 but if I make this call on line 20 then everything is fine. It doesn't work that way. What happens after the error line is of no importance.

Comment: But for some reason << camera.lookAt(0,0,0) >> does work OK when OrbitControls are active.

Comment: only by coincidence.